# how to add transition effect with CSS

Tags: css, toggle

I've played with following code to make softly and gently transtion effect when  onclick. Toggle elements opens itself very fast and hard. I would like make it a bit softer. Actually I don't have any idea which class or ID or selector would make affect it.

Demo:    [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/atahta/17u76rz9/)

CSS:

```
.toggle-box + label:before {
    background-color: #4F5150;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    content: "+";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the following rules in this way:

```
.toggle-box + label + div {
  max-height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: max-height 0.15s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle-box:checked + label + div {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: max-height 3s linear;
}
```

Max-height needs to be setted to a value which your div will never reach.

Here is updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17u76rz9/2/)

Comment: Opening transition works well,but while closing it is still very fast, by the way is there also a chance  to close the other one, when I open any of them?

Comment: You can play with values in transition property (in this case 0.15s for closing and 3s for opening), but for closing needs to be fast because there is the problem of "+" which immediately toggle to "-" on click

Comment: To close other one you have to use javascript or jquery

Comment: I tried but I couldn't, so I'll use it as it is, thank for your answer